# How to send the JSON data in rest web services?

Tags: json, web-services, rest, ibm-mobilefirst

How to send the JSON data in rest web services?
    I have a json object which contains product Id,store Id,price,product Unit,quantity 
    values.Here All the values are integer only except product Unit value.
    Now, I want to send these values into rest web services.
    Could you please give any samples or any valuable suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have tagged this with the Worklight tag, I'm going to assume you meant to ask how to send json data from a worklight client to an external REST service. In order to do this in Worklight, you need to use a Worklight HTTP adapter. See the documentation here: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/04_02_HTTP_adapter_-_Communicating_with_HTTP_back-end_systems.pdf

After creating the Worklight adapter, you can then send your JSON data from the client like this:

```
/**********************************************************************************
*                           Http Adapter call
**********************************************************************************/
function callAdapter(){

    var myJSONObject = {
        productId: 123, 
        storeId: 123, 
        price: 342, 
        productUnit: "myUnit",
        quantity: 4
    };

    var invocationData = {
            adapter : 'MyHttpAdapter',
            procedure : 'myAdapterProcedure',
            parameters : [myJSONObject]
    };

    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
        onSuccess : success,
        onFailure : failure
    });
}

function success(response){
    console.log("adapter Success");
    console.log(response);
}

function failure(response){
    console.log("adapter Failure");
    console.log(response);
}
```

Comment: Yes..absolutely correct.I did my code this way...But i need to receive this json obj in my webservices..I dnt know how to do that.Now am having json object that contains all the values such as product Id,store id,etc.So I want to post these object in my webservices...How to do that?Pls tell me.

Comment: Actually what i have to do is,send my json data into my db through rest web service.So that i asked how to post this json data in my controller(webservices)?I hope now you can understand my question. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON input:

```
{
  "productId": "p123",
  "storeId": "s456",
  "price": 12.34,
  "productUnit": "u789",
  "quantity": 42
}
```

The JAXB class:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class MyJaxbBean {
    public String productId;
    public String storeId;
    public double price;
    public String productUnit;
    public int quantity;

    public MyJaxbBean() {} // JAXB needs this

    public MyJaxbBean(String productId, String storeId, double price, String productUnit, int quantity) {
        // set members
    }
}
```

The JAX-RS method.

```
@PUT
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response putMyBean(MyJaxbBean theInput) {
    // Do something with theInput

    return Response.created().build();
}
```

See [the documentation of Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json) (the RI for JAX-RS) for details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But I want to send product Id,store Id,price,product Unit,quantity as parameters in web services.Can you please tell?

Comment: @Kiran You should be able to write a class with these properties. Please at least try.

Comment: Ok..Cool..!I want to send these parametrs as jsonobject.Tell me how to receive jsonobject in web service?

Comment: I did. `@Consumes("application/json")` is enough to map JSON to `MyJaxbBean`.