# Send JSON data to Jersey Rest Webservice using Worklight Adapter

Tags: json, rest, jersey, ibm-mobilefirst

I tried to call rest service using http adapter, but got unsupported media type exception.

My adapter and server side code is as follows

var invocationData = {
            adapter : 'MyHttpAdapter',
            procedure : 'myAdapterProcedure',
            parameters : [myJSONObject]
    };

```
WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData, {
    onSuccess : success,
    onFailure : failure
});
```

function myAdapterProcedure(prarams) {

```
var input = {
    method : 'put',
    returnedContentType : 'json',
    path : 'mobile/rest/notes/getMyWebData',
    parameters : prarams

};
return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
```

}

server side:
        @PUT
    @Path("addNotes")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String addNotes(MyNotes pVo)  throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("1231231" + pVo);
            return pVo;
         }

Detailed exception:
Failed to parse JSON string
Apache Tomcat/6.0.35 - Error report

## HTTP Status 415 - Unsupported Media Type

**type** Status report

**message** Unsupported Media Type

**description** The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method (Unsupported Media Type).

#### Apache Tomcat/6.0.35

FWLSE0101E: Caused by:  [project GMobile]java.io.IOException: Unexpected character '<' on line 1, column 1 
                                                                                                               com.worklight.common.log.filters.ErrorFilter

Tried with Put, Post method invocations and got the same exception.  tried with '@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })  on server method still get the same error.  Can anyone let me know what am I missing here...

Found the same issue here, without the solution.
ref:
[How to send the JSON data in rest web services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781775/how-to-send-the-json-data-in-rest-web-services/18781845)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check your REST service with a REST client (i'm using firefox add-on "RESTClient" to test my REST services outside of worklight) ?

If it's OK on the REST service side, then you need to check the headers in your http adapter "input" object.

you have to set the content-type params to "application/json" in the http request. To do so, add the "headers" attribute as below:

```
var input = {
   method : 'put',
   returnedContentType : 'json',
   path : 'mobile/rest/notes/getMyWebData',
   parameters : params,
   headers : 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

};

Regards.