# REST endpoint returning multiple JSON types

Tags: rest

We're discussing a REST infrastructure, as one of the endpoints currently can return two different types of data:

If it cannot find any objects it returns something like this:

```
{
   "key1": "value1",
   "key2": "value2"
}
```

If it can find any data, it returns something like this:

```
{
   "key3": "value3",
   "key4": [   {
      "key5": "value5",
      "output":       [
                  {
            "name": "value6",
            "value": "value7"
         },
                  {
            "name": "value8",
            "value": 0
         }
      ]
   }]
}
```

I don't think this is very REST-full, but I'm relatively new to REST design.

What are good places for guidance on how to design such responses?

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18781775/how-to-send-the-json-data-in-rest-web-services) will help you out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of opinions on this. My view is that if you cannot find any objects, you return a `404`. If you find one or more objects, you return a `200` with the body containing the objects.

How you structure those objects in a `200` body response is up to you. My preference has always been straight JSON object for a single item, or array for multiple.

Here are some examples:

`GET /api/users/20000000` returns `404`

`GET /api/users/1` returns `200` with a body of `{"name":"John Smith","id":"1","email":"john@smith.net"}`

`GET /api/users` returns `200` with a body of `[{"name":"John Smith","id":"1","email":"john@smith.net"},{"name":"Jill Smith","id":"2","email":"jill@smith.net"},{"name":"Someone Else","id":"3","email":"someone@else.com"}]` (**note** the array format)

`GET /api/users/1,2` returns `200` with a body of `[{"name":"John Smith","id":"1","email":"john@smith.net"},{"name":"Jill Smith","id":"2","email":"jill@smith.net"}]` (**note** the array format)

FYI, I had to implement something like this for an express project, so I standardized it with booster http://github.com/deitch/booster

Comment: I'm not in the JavaScript realm of things, so I can't use booster. Your answer did help me with an internal discussion here on how to organize things. Much appreciated. One more thing: see next comment.

Comment: What would you do if a user didn't have any attributes (yes: the objects returned in our API can be empty): just return `[{}]` for them? And why the distinction between `{...}` and `[{...},{...}]`. Why not always return an array like `[{...}]`?

Comment: Well, then, I definitely am glad it was helpful (if in an unexpected way). :-)

Comment: Yes, if there is an actual resource, but it has no attributes, I would return `{}` or `[{}]` depending on the case. As for why not always array? Because I want to be consistent. GET `/api/users` is a query, so it returns an array; GET `/api/users/1` is a GET for a single item; GET `/api/users/1,2` is a GET for multiple items so it returns an array.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In this case it is returning a bag of settings for a specific object. That can be anywhere from 0 till about 30 key-value pairs. So the result I am opting for is from `[]` for an empty bag to `[{key1,value1},{key2,value2},...]` for a bag with multiple pairs. Around the bag is some meta-information, hence the slightly more complex structure in the question.

Comment: I guess as long as you are comfortable that you will *always* return a single resource, just that it might have multiple key/value pairs, you will be safe with an array. However, if you ever have to return multiple resources on a single call, you will be stuck with an inability to use an array. Might be safer to return an object with an array embedded: `{props:[{key1:value1},{key2:value2}]}` etc. so in the future you can have an array of objects

Comment: Thanks for that. Very enlightening.